# Two Trees: one Tree's nodes contains a List of objects; the 2nd Tree's objects contains references to the first Tree's objects. Can it be done in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, tree, ref

I want to build 2 Tree structures. The first Tree will contain nodes, each with List of my `Range` object:

```
class Range {
     public DateTime Start { get; set; }
     public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

The Tree structure will look like this:

[image]

I then want a 2nd Tree build *from* the 1st Tree. It will have a similar structure, however, when changes are made to the Range object in the 2nd Tree, I want the Range objects in the first tree to also change. Effectively, I need to hold references or pointers to the Range objects in the first Tree:

**Tree #2:**

[image]

C# is my language of preference and I know you can use the `ref` keyword, but I wonder if C# is really the right language for this or do I need something with pointers like C++?

Comment: In C++, use `std::shared_ptr<Range>`.  Your use case is why they're called "shared pointers".

Comment: You need a mapping between the trees in one node against the nodes in other node.  You can use a KeyValuePair<node name, node>.  I like using a dictionary which makes is easy to do the lookup.  Dictionary<node name, node>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes you can.**

You declared Range as `class` (as opposed to `struct`), therefore you will only be handling references (as opposed to the actual values).

For instance, your `List<Range>` is a collection of references to `Range` objects.

`Range` having reference semantics means a few things in C#, for example:

- It only compares equal to the exact same instance
- A `Range` variable can hold `null`
- You always pass references, and if that's not what you want, you need to clone it explicitly
- ...

You may like a quick refresher on [reference vs. value semantics](http://blog.s-schoener.com/2018-03-04-value-semantics-csharp/).